# 3D Model movement, finding a better way to move a 3d model

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Lets say i am trying to move a 3d model and to keep it simple I am just going to move it on the x axis. I start at position 0.0 and move it to position 10.0.

The problem is that depending on the speed i move at i end up with position errors which then means i need to snap back to position 10.0.

for example if the speed is 3.0 then each frame i add 3.0 to the x position 
0.0
3.0
6.0
9.0
12.0

if I want to stop when I get to 10.0 i could use this code

```
 if(model.x <= 10.0f)
    model.x += speed * FrameTime;
else 
    model.x = 10.0f;
```

however the model will reach position 12.0 before it realises it has past 10.0

this also means the faster i move the bigger the error will be.

Can anyone please suggest a better way to move models so that the error is eliminated or at least reduced so it doesn't look like my model bounces back.

Comment: Why don't you just clamp it to 10.0 after you apply your update? (e.g. `if (model.x > 10.0f) model.x = 10.0f;` Granted that will produce an unnatural jerkiness when it snaps to 10.0f all of a sudden. You might add a damper of some sort if that is unacceptable.

Comment: The above code does exactly that and thats what i am trying to get rid of the jerkiness. can you exapand on the "damper"

Comment: @Rob85: No, it doesn't. The above code checks tries to clamp it _before_ it does the actual update - which means that if the update increments it past `10.0`, it will have no idea until the next frame.

Comment: @Rob85: No, the above code does not do exactly that. The only time it is snapped to **10.0** is the second time this update occurs. Clamping to 10.0f would be a separate `if (...)` applied after the two branches you have shown. In fact, you don't even need any of those branches. Simply use: `model.x += speed * FrameTime;    if (model.x > 10.0f) model.x = 10.0f;`

Comment: ahhh yes i see, so before i draw the next frame i snap it to 10.0 which should almost solve the issue. I understand. I will give that a try, thankyou both of you

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman thank you very much for your answer and voithos for the added help, can you right your reply in an answer and i will accept it. I have tested it and it is now very smooth so i am very happy with that. Almost a bit disapointed at my self for not getting that on my own :-(

Comment: To be honest, I like user23422's solution better. It handles the situation where speed is negative, which what I was suggesting did not. I would rather you accept that answer than something I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float minX = 0;
float maxX = 10;
float dx = speed * FrameTime;

model.x = Math.max(minX, Math.min(model.x + dx, maxX));
```

Perhaps not the most legible solution, but it does what you need in one line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and that works great if i want to move from 0 - 10 how can rearrange this method so i can move from 10 - 0. Since

Comment: The dx value represents the change for the frame. Hence, going the negative direction, you can either negate dx, or make speed negative (which would do the same, but probably in a cleaner way). As for the clamping, that doesn't need to change.